# case espression for particular condition

Tags: sql

how to assign value to other column based on condition 
like

suppose there is id `1 3 5` and number column,
if `1` and `3` are present for particular sid of `101`

```
sid id  number 
101  1    4
101  3    4
101  2    4

sid id number
102 1   4
103 3   12
```

if 1 and 3 is present for sid then value 4 should be assigned

Comment: pls. tag the DBMS (MySQL, MS SQL Server, Oracle) which u r using

Comment: and case is not statement, it is expression.

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense.  Is the data "before" data or "after" data.  Where is `id = 5`?  Would it be sufficient to return just one row with `101 4`?  Is it a coincidence that "4 = 3 + 1" ?

Comment: pls give more details.

Comment: after data and no all the rows should be assigned 4

Comment: it is like if the id is 1 then should assign 4

Comment: if id is 3 then should assign 12 to number

Comment: if the sid has both the id  1 and 3 then 4 should be assigned to all the rows

Comment: Show us the expected result table! (Formatted text, not images.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use it.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (sid INT, id INT)
INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(101,  1    ),
(101,  3    ),
(101,  2    ),
(102,  1    ),
(103,  3    )

SELECT T1.*, T2.number  FROM @T T1
 INNER JOIN (SELECT sid, ( MIN(id) * 4 ) number 
        FROM @T GROUP BY sid)  T2 ON T1.sid = T2.sid
```

Result:

```
sid         id          number
----------- ----------- -----------
101         1           4
101         3           4
101         2           4
102         1           4
103         3           12
```

Answer (score 0):

> > if the sid has both the id 1 and 3 then 4 should be assigned to all the rows

else

> > if the id is 1 then should assign 4
> >
> > if id is 3 then should assign 12 to number

In standard SQL you'd use analytic functions to look into all records of a sid, when deciding which number to show.

```
select
  sid,
  id,
  case when count(case when id = 1 then 1 end) over (partition by sid) > 0
        and count(case when id = 3 then 1 end) over (partition by sid) > 0 then 4
       when id = 1 then 4
       when id = 3 then 12
  end as number
from mytable;
```